Get data from observable without subscribe in component
I have user data in an observable, I want to get that data to get length of the users and specific condition to route to different page.
Without using subscribe, how can I check the logic
I tried subscribe - it works but my use case is without subscribe
I tried tap but no avail.

without knowing use case problem cannot be solved share the code that uses this Observable

Using async I was able to solve this.

An approach is to handle navigation directly in a service using RxJS operators:
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { UserService } from './user.service'; 
import { takeUntilDestroyed } from '@angular/core/rxjs-interop';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NavigationService {
  constructor(private userService: UserService, private router: Router) {}

  checkUsersAndNavigate(destroyRef: DestroyRef) {
    return this.userService.getUsers().pipe(
      takeUntilDestroyed(destroyRef), //to unsuscribe
      tap(users => {
        if (users.length > 0) {
          this.router.navigate(['/some-page']);
        } else {
          this.router.navigate(['/other-page']);
        }
   
      })
    );
  }
}

In order to receive notifications of changes or events in an observable, it is necessary to subscribe to it.
example:
  export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
  destroyRef = inject(DestroyRef)
  constructor(private navigationService: NavigationService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.navigationService.checkUsersAndNavigate(destroyRef).subscribe();
  }
}

